# Why is sheet being included in VBA when i've asked for it not to be

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know why not all sheets are being excluded as defined in my code below?  It seems that sheet 'Asset' is still being included.  Many thanks

```
Sub Run_Me_To_Fix_Columns()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

'------------------------------------------------------------------
'List the names of the worksheets to exclude from Sub resizingColumns
'------------------------------------------------------------------

    Const excludeSheets As String = "Control,DIVA_Report,Asset"

'------------------------------------------------------------------

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","))) Then
        Call resizingColumns(ws)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub resizingColumns(ws As Worksheet)
       With ws
        ws.Range("A:AZ").ColumnWidth = 10
    End With
    For i = 1 To 24
        Numbers = WorksheetFunction.Count(ws.Columns(i))
        Text = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(i)) - Numbers
        If Numbers < Text Then
            ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to request an exact match on the *[match_type]* parameter. `Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","), 0)`.

Comment: My bad, it is showing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a good idea to have some basic debugging skills in your toolchest. For example, you could insert code like the following *before* your test:

```
For Each s In Split(excludeSheets, ",")
    MsgBox "EX: [" & s & "]: " & CStr(len(s))
Next

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    MsgBox "WS: [" & ws.Name & "]: " & CStr(len(ws.Name))
Next

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    MsgBox "MATCH: " & ws.Name & ": " & CStr(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ",")))
    MsgBox "ISERR: " & ws.Name & ": " & CStr(IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","))))
Next
```

This will show you the values you're checking (with lengths to ensure they don't have unexpected white-space before or after, something that's bitten me before with sheet names).

---

Further on that, I'll actually walk you through a decent debugging session so you can gain some skills in that area. First, create a new workbook with the sheets "Sheet1" through "Sheet5", and enter the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Const excludeSheets As String = "Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet5"
    
    For Each s In Split(excludeSheets, ",")
        MsgBox "EX: [" & s & "]: " & CStr(Len(s))
    Next

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        MsgBox "WS: [" & ws.Name & "]: " & CStr(Len(ws.Name))
    Next

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        MsgBox "MATCH: [" & ws.Name & "]: " & CStr(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ",")))
        MsgBox "ISERR: [" & ws.Name & "]: " & CStr(IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","))))
    Next

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","))) Then
            MsgBox "GOT: [" & ws.Name & "]"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When you run that, you'll see the following message boxes:

```
EX: [Sheet2]: 6
EX: [Sheet3]: 6
EX: [Sheet5]: 6

WS: [Sheet1]: 6
WS: [Sheet2]: 6
WS: [Sheet3]: 6
WS: [Sheet4]: 6
WS: [Sheet5]: 6

MATCH: [Sheet1]: Error 2042
ISERR: [Sheet1]: True

MATCH: [Sheet2]: 1
ISERR: [Sheet2]: False

MATCH: [Sheet3]: 2
ISERR: [Sheet3]: False

MATCH: [Sheet4]: 2
ISERR: [Sheet4]: False

MATCH: [Sheet5]: 3
ISERR: [Sheet5]: False

GOT: [Sheet1]
```

You can see from that output that the only sheet output was `Sheet1` despite the fact that `Sheet4` is not in the exclude list. And, from the `MATCH` lines, both `Sheet3` and `Sheet4` appear to have been found in position 2 of the exclude list.

So that immediately tells you where the problem lies, Excel appears to be doing something wrong. But, in fact, it's doing exactly what you told it to do. Going to the [documentation for the `Match` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx), we see this little snippet:

> **`expression.Match (Lookup_value, Lookup_array, Match_type)`**
>
> - If `Match_type` is 1, `Match` finds the largest value that is less than or equal to `Lookup_value`. `Lookup_array` must be placed in ascending order: ...-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE.
> - If `Match_type` is 0, `Match` finds the first value that is exactly equal to `Lookup_value`. `Lookup_array` can be in any order.
> - If `Match_type` is -1, `Match` finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to `Lookup_value`. `Lookup_array` must be placed in descending order: TRUE, FALSE, Z-A, ...2, 1, 0, -1, -2, ..., and so on.
> - If `Match_type` is omitted, it is assumed to be 1.

Note that last clause. Because you're choosing the default match type of "largest less than or equal to", `Sheet1` causes an error because there is no entry less than or equal to it in the exclude list.

However, for `Sheet4`, there *is* a match. `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` are both less than or equal to `Sheet4`, and `Sheet3` is the largest of them, hence why it's "found" in position 2.

You may well find even *stranger* results in your situation since your worksheets my not be sorted alphabetically.

The solution then is to specify an exact match rather than using the default (the `0` parameter added to the `Match` call):

```
If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","), 0)) Then
```

Comment: + 1 I absolutely agree :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and i agree i need to learn more on VBA and debugging as i am a beginner. Unfortunately i'm still receiving an error, this time i'm able to see that the below code is failing with Type Mismatch 13 error `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets MsgBox "MATCH: " & ws.Name & ": " & Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ",")) Next` Any more help.. I have confirmed the lengths are the same and it seems to be the worksheet name which is causing a problem, because ASSET_CONTROL fails, however CONTROL_ASSET works... Very Strange!

Comment: @cRIMSOnffs, that's possibly due to the fact that only one is sorted as per the requirements of `match(...,1)`. My latest update on using `match(...,0)` should fix your problems.